# The social-django package shows error while trying to login to facebook

Tags: django, facebook

When iam trying to  use the facebook  social-django as a package in django its shows an error like ,

```
Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to 
this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://
```

I am created an app in fb and its having an id and key that already added in  settings.py.

In fb app redirect url is like :

https://localhost:8000/

For https i  tried 'sslserer' but it not working properly !

Comment: You need to use HTTPS “before” already, just having your redirect_uri be an HTTPS one is not enough. The Website platform setting should also use an HTTPS URL already.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook do not support the host `127.0.0.1:8000` or `localhost:8000`.
If you are using linux/ubuntu then add below line at the end of file `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.1.1       myproject.com
```

After go to your fb app and change the redirecturl from `localhost:8000` to `myproject.com:8000`.

Comment: How can i made like myproject.com

Comment: which OS are you using ?

Comment: ubuntu . using django 2

Comment: how can i change 127.0.0.1:8000 to mysite.com

Comment: access `myproject.com:8000` in your local machine. you will get local dev server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171000/discussion-between-anjitha-and-anjaneyulu-batta).